# Share strings between classes of the same component's TS file in Angular2 to print in template

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I'm trying to print some strings in a template but I can't find a way to do it like this:

Template:

```
{{ MyComponentStrings.string1 }}
{{ MyComponentStrings.string2 }}
{{ MyComponentStrings.string3 }}
```

Component:

```
export class MyComponentStrings {
  string1 = 'text1';
  string2 = 'text2';
  string3 = 'text3';
}

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-mycomponent',
    styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
})

export class MyComponent {
  // ...component code here
  // if I want to print i.e. string1 this won't work either
  console.log(MyComponentStrings.string1);
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this or I must declare all the strings inside of MyComponent? I'm trying to have all those strings outside of the component class or in another component to avoid a wall of strings in the code, and I need to define them since they will be used multiple times on the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance Of **`MyComponentStrings`**  and access it,

```
constructor(){
    let comString = new MyComponentStrings();
    console.log(comString.string1);
}
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7f9cgz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**